# check convergence of $\int _1^{\infty }\:\frac{\sin\left(x-1\right)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> I"m trying to check if $$\int _1^{\infty }\:\frac{\sin\left(x-1\right)}{x}dx$$ is convergence  or not .

I tried that $\sin(x-1)\le 1 , x\in [1,\infty)$ but then i get that $\frac{\sin\left(x-1\right)}{x}\le\frac{1}{x}$ but this don't help alot .

I also tried to set $f(x)=\frac{\sin\left(x-1\right)}{x}$ and $g(x) =\frac{1}{x} $
 and to find $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)}{g\left(x\right)}\right)$

any idea how i can solve it ?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to integrate by parts on a compact [1,a] ?

Comment: @Atmos no but i"ll try it right now

Answer (score 3):

Hint $$\sin(x-1) = \sin(x) \cos(1) -\sin(1) \cos(x). $$

and we know that $$\int _1^{\infty }\:\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}dx$$

converges and  $$\int _1^{\infty }\:\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{x}dx$$ converges too by Dirichlet test.

Comment: Why does the second integral diverge ?

Comment: @Atmos sorry I think it converges

Comment: Not really ^^  but i thought -Ci(1) existed. For me, your argument is absolutely good but it proves that this integral converges.

Comment: Well, if we could use Dirichlet test, the conclusion would directly follow from it without expanding $\sin(x-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Let $M>1$. Then integrating by parts,
$$
\int_1^M\frac{\sin\left(x-1\right)}{x}dx=\left[\frac{-\cos\left(x-1\right)}{x}\right]_1^M-\int_1^M\frac{\cos\left(x-1\right)}{x^2}dx
$$ By letting $M \to \infty$, one sees that the given integral is *convergent* since the latter integral is convergent.

Comment: what i did ,  Let $f(x)=sin(x-1) , g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and then we get that $|\int _1^Msin\left(x-1\right)\:|=|-\cos \left(1-x\right)|^M_0\le2$ ... then we get by Dirichlet test that the integral is convergent ( $g(x)$monotonic goes to 0 and $\int _{\:}^{\:}f\left(x\right)$ is bounded for  $M\in(1,\infty)$)

Comment: @J.Doe What you did is correct too :) (In your comment above you mean $f$ is bounded, **not** $\int f$ is bounded).